# Looking for multiples substrings within a SQL string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2005

I have several occurrences of differences strings in the columns, like this example

`'dsasdasdsd'+'ewewewew'+'45454545'+(avg('uuuuuuu'))`

I need to split this string into several columns with the substrings that are between 
aphostropes

like this:

```
Column 1 = dsasdasdsd
Column 2 = ewewewew
Column 3 = 45454545
Column 4 = uuuuuuu
```

The numbers of apperances are random, thefore the length of the original column is also not fixed (from 50 char to > 1000)

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Which character or string is splinting the whole string ?

Comment: do you need to do this in a T-SQL command?  Stored procedure? View?  Let me know how you want the answer and I might be able to help.

Comment: SQL server 2005, the caracheter using to split is the apostrophe as showed in the example, could be a t-sql or sp any will do

Comment: 0
 
down vote 
favorite  I have several occurrences of differences strings in the columns, like this example

'dsasdasdsd'+'ewewewew'+'45454545'+(avg('uuuuuuu'))

I need to split this string into several columns with the substrings that are between aphostropes

like this:

Column 1 = dsasdasdsd Column 2 = ewewewew Column 3 = 45454545 Column 4 = uuuuuuu The numbers of apperances are random, thefore the lenght of the original column is also nhot fixed (from 50 char to > 1000)

Can some one assist?

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @InStr VarChar(1000) = '''dsasdasdsd''+''ewewewew''+''45454545''+(avg(''uuuuuuu''))'''
DECLARE @intStart INT = 0
DECLARE @intEnd INT = 1
DECLARE @ColNo INT = 1
DECLARE @MyString VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @SelectString VARCHAR(8000) = 'SELECT '



WHILE(@intStart < LEN(@InStr) )
BEGIN 
    SELECT @intStart = CHARINDEX(CHAR(39), @InStr, 0) + 1
    SELECT @intEnd = CHARINDEX(CHAR(39), @InStr, @intStart)  
    SELECT @SelectString = @SelectString + CHAR(39) + SUBSTRING(@InStr, @intStart, @intEnd - @intStart) + CHAR(39) + ' As [Column ' + CAST(@ColNo As Varchar) + '],'
    SELECT @InStr = SUBSTRING(@InStr, @intEnd + 1, LEN(@InStr)-@intEnd )

    SET @ColNo = @ColNo +1

END

SELECT @SelectString = LEFT(@SelectString, Len(@SelectString) -1)

EXEC (@SelectString)
```

I have been playing with this and this does run but unfortunately I don't have time right now to carry on with it but maybe you can improve on this?

HTH

Comment: Works!, will use to build my sp. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
create table tSqlStrings (sText nvarchar(1000))

insert tSqlStrings values('''dsasdasdsd''+''ewewewew''+''45454545''+(avg(''uuuuuuu''))')

create table tResults (
  sColumn1 nvarchar(1000)
  ,sColumn2 nvarchar(1000)
  ,sColumn3 nvarchar(1000)
  ,sColumn4 nvarchar(1000)
)
```

and

```
DELETE tResults

DECLARE @sText nvarchar(1000) = (
  SELECT
    sText
  FROM
    tSqlStrings
)

DECLARE @lBegin int = CHARINDEX('''',@sText)
DECLARE @lEnd int = charindex('''',
                              substring(@sText,
                                        CHARINDEX('''',@sText)+1,
                                        len(@sText)))
DECLARE @sText0 nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @sColumn1 nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @sColumn2 nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @sColumn3 nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @sColumn4 nvarchar(1000)

DECLARE @iCnt int = 1
while @iCnt<=4
  --(0<len(@sText) and 0<@lBegin and 0<@lEnd)
BEGIN

  SET @sText0 = substring(@sText,@lBegin+1,@lEnd-2)
  IF @iCnt=1 begin SET @sColumn1=@sText0 end
  IF @iCnt=2 begin SET @sColumn2=@sText0 end
  IF @iCnt=3 begin SET @sColumn3=@sText0 end
  IF @iCnt=4 begin SET @sColumn4=@sText0 end

  set @sText = substring(@sText,@lBegin + @lEnd+2,len(@sText))

  SET @lBegin = CHARINDEX('''',@sText)
  SET @lEnd = charindex('''',
                        substring(@sText,
                                  CHARINDEX('''',@sText)+1,
                                  len(@sText)))
  SET @iCnt = @iCnt+1
END

INSERT
    tResults (sColumn1,sColumn2,sColumn3,sColumn4)
    VALUES (@sColumn1,@sColumn2,@sColumn3,@sColumn4)

SELECT * FROM tResults
```

on [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a1b1/1/0)

Comment: This is fixed to 4 columns but the OP has stated that "numbers of apperances are random".

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it's absolutely true. However, you can not get away the dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to achieve this using CHARINDEX() and SUBSTRING()
Following example shows for splitting to 2 columns. When it has more columns, query will be get little more complicated. However, you can follow this to build your query.

```
SELECT OriginalColumn
, SUBSTRING(OriginalColumn, 1,CHARINDEX('x',OriginalColumn,1)-1) AS Column1
, SUBSTRING(OriginalColumn, CHARINDEX('x',OriginalColumn,1) + 1 ,CHARINDEX('x',OriginalColumn,CHARINDEX('x',OriginalColumn,1)-1)) AS Column2
FROM YourTable
```

I have used "x" as the delimiter in the example. Following is a sample result

[image]

Comment: Works, but I need the subtring bewween the markers, in may case aphostrophes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
declare @delim char
set @delim = ''''
declare @str nvarchar(max)
declare @substr nvarchar(max)
declare @newstr nvarchar(max)
declare @tmpTable table (partStrings nvarchar(max))
declare @count int
set @count = 0
select @str = <***Your String***>
while(charindex(@delim,@str) != 0)
begin
set @count = @count + 1
Select @substr = substring(@str,1,charindex(@delim,@str)-1)
if((@count % 2) = 0)
begin
    insert into @tmpTable values(@substr)
end
Set @newstr = substring(@str,charindex(@delim,@str)+1,len(@str)-charindex(@delim,@str))

set @str = @newstr
end
select partStrings from @tmpTable
```